# Отключение действия android браузера при двойном касании

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

Что нужно сделать, чтобы отключить уменьшение экрана при быстром двойном касании в android браузере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[viewport](http://frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport)

```
<html>
    <head> <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'> </head>
    <body> qeqqe </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Для safari по умолчанию `user-scalable=yes`, незнаю насколько на сегодня это рабочий вариант,  раньше было `content='user-scalable=no'`

Comment: У меня стоит `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, height=device-height"`, но даже с этим не работает

Comment: @nulh, странно, а у меня работает. Как насчёт `maximum-scale=1.0`? Хотя это тоже вряд ли поможет

Comment: Нет, не работает

Comment: Ошибка в вопросе.. Оно не увеличивается, а уменьшается. `minimum-scale=1.0` пробовал

Comment: @nulh, есть ссылка или ip, где есть полный контент?

Comment: [Здесь](http://rounverse.herokuapp.com)

Comment: @nulh, прозвучит странно, но если убрать `<td>` теги в таблице `id='games'`, начинает работать. Точнее из-за `id='g5'` и `id='g10'`. Причину пока не знаю

Comment: Спасибо. Постараюсь отгадать, в чем причина

Comment: @nulh, если отгадаешь, напиши тут, пожалуйста, а то мне тоже интересно почему. Там не зависит от записи, скорее всего то, что при наличии пяти и более `td` тегов таблица не помещается в какую-то область и срабатывает уменьшение

Comment: @nulh, Так и есть, таблица не помщается в ширину. Можно у `table` указать `style='font-size: 14px'` и всё будет ок

Comment: Спасибо, помогло